# Why do lmodern and textcomp inhibit display style?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, displaystyle, lmodern, textcomp

## MWE 1

The following MWE is doing what I want:

```
\documentclass[b4paper,14pt,english,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % For French accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MATH et TiKZ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
         V_{ijk} &= \int \int_D (x-y)f_{ik}(x)f_{jk}(y)dxdy
    \end{align}    
\end{document}
```

## Output of MWE 1

[image]

## MWE 2

However, adding: `\usepackage{lmodern, textcomp}` destroy my math output, especially the integrals:

```
\documentclass[b4paper,14pt,english,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % For French accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, textcomp}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MATH et TiKZ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
         V_{ijk} &= \int \int_D (x-y)f_{ik}(x)f_{jk}(y)dxdy
    \end{align}    
\end{document}
```

## Output of MWE 2

[image]

My question is, how can I have displaystyle in math mode, using `\usepackage{lmodern, textcomp}`.

## Note

1. I need `\usepackage{lmodern, textcomp}` in my preambule, otherwise my all memoir won't compile.
2. I also tried `\displaystyle`, but that didn't change anything

Comment: unrelated but don't use utf8x, utf8 is more compatible and quite sufficient.

Comment: I uploaded a new version of `fixcmex` to CTAN. With the new version (1.1) you can just add `\usepackage{fixcmex}` to your preamble.

Comment: @egreg I was trying to work out why the present version of `fixcmex` wasn't working...

Comment: Why do you use double `$\int$` instead of `$\iint$`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: @egreg Alright, this is working now, thanks

Comment: @Sebastiano The reason is quite simple: I'm learning TeX by myself and had no idea it exists :) Thanks ;)

Comment: As of 2020, you no longer need `textcomp`. All its symbols are now in the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: @UlrileFischer `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` redefines `\show`. Ack!

Answer (score 2):

Both MWE1 and MWE2 (lmodern) examples use display style (\displaystyle). The problem is the font definition for the math extended characters coming with lmodern, file omxlmex.fd, contents:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{lmex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}{%
   <->sfixed*lmex10%
   }{}
```

So the big operators are always from a 10pt font, regardless of the document font size. (That reminds me of latex2.09 days.)

The fix is/was to use package exscale. Or, more up to date, the fixcmex package, as indicated in a comment from egreg.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem about `\displaystyle`. So I commented out `\usepackage{lmodern}` but retained `\usepackage{textcomp}` and it seems to work fine now.